# Fwrite function cuts off data in output .tar file

Tags: c, fwrite

I have a piece of code that is designed to replicate the creation of a .tar file albeit a simpler version of it. It will take in 2 .txt files and produce a .tar file of the 2 files. Below is my code for doing so. However when opening the .tar file it is corrupted and sure enough, by viewing the data in a hex editor the data is cut off.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<ctype.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

#define  RECORDSIZE  512
#define  NAMSIZ      100
#define  TUNMLEN      32
#define  TGNMLEN      32

struct header {
    char name[NAMSIZ];//needed
    char size[12];//needed
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    //argv[1] file1 argv[2] file2
    char* file1 = argv[1];
    char* file2 = argv[2];
    FILE* f;
    int lSize;
    char temp_length[10];
    char* file1_data, * file2_data;
    int result;

    //char* output_str = (char*)malloc(sizeof)

    f = fopen(file1, "rb");
    if (f == NULL) {
        printf("File error!");
        return 1;
    }
    fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END);
    lSize = ftell(f);
    fseek(f, 0, SEEK_SET);
    file1_data = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * lSize);
    if (file1_data == NULL) {
        printf("Memory error!");
        return 1;
    }
    result = fread(file1_data, 1, lSize, f);
    file1_data[result] = '\0';
    fclose(f);
    sprintf(temp_length, "%d", lSize);
    struct header* h1 = malloc(sizeof(struct header));
    strcpy(h1->name, file1);
    strcpy(h1->size, temp_length);
    printf("Name:%s Value:%s\n", h1->name, h1->size);
    printf("File 1 data:%s\n", file1_data);


    f = fopen(file2, "rb");
    if (f == NULL) {
        printf("File error!");
        return 1;
    }
    fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END);
    lSize = ftell(f);
    fseek(f, 0, SEEK_SET);
    file2_data = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * lSize);
    if (file2_data == NULL) {
        printf("Memory error!");
        return 1;
    }
    result = fread(file2_data, 1, lSize, f);
    file2_data[result] = '\0';
    fclose(f);
    sprintf(temp_length, "%d", lSize);
    struct header* h2 = malloc(sizeof(struct header));
    strcpy(h2->name, file1);
    strcpy(h2->size, temp_length);
    
    printf("Name:%s Value:%s\n", h2->name, h2->size);
    printf("File 2 data:%s\n", file2_data);

    //allocate mem for output buffer

    int total = sizeof(struct header) + sizeof(struct header) + sizeof(file1_data) + sizeof(file2_data);
    printf("total length %d\n", total);

    f = fopen("Result.tar", "wb");

    //fwrite(input,length,no of ele,output buffer)
    fwrite(h1, sizeof(struct header), 1, f);
    fwrite(file1_data, sizeof(file1_data), 1, f);
    fwrite(h2, sizeof(struct header), 1, f);
    fwrite(file2_data, sizeof(file2_data), 1, f);
    if (fwrite != 0)
        printf("Contents to file written successfully !\n");
    else
        printf("Error writing file !\n");
    fclose(f);
}
```

First file name: File1.txt
Data within:

```
This is File 1.
```

Second file name: File2.txt
Data within:

```
This is File 2.
File 2 has more data inside.
```

Decoded text output:

```
File1.txt�ÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍ31�ÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍThis is File1.txt�ÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍ63�ÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍThis is
```

As observed, File 2's name as well as the subsequent data has been cut off. I've been debugging but I'm unsure where am I going wrong as fwrite does not return a 0 hence, I'm assuming it's successful.

As the print statements are exactly what I expected, I don't think the reading of the data is the issue but rather the fwrite function. Hence I would like to seek advice on it.

Comment: Yes, apologies for the confusion, I pasted the decoded text instead

Comment: `file1_data[result] = '\0';` This is writing out of bounds.

Comment: `sizeof(file1_data)` That is the size of a pointer. Not the size of allocated memory. You need to keep `lsize` for both files.

Comment: @Gerhardh, I see however, without changing that to a null character I seem to get weird chunks of data at the end of the string such as ²²²². Would there be a better of way doing so?

Comment: That is not surprising. Passing a non-nul-terminated character sequence to any function expecting a string is undefined behaviour. Same is true for assigning values to memory that doesn't belong to you. That means you must add `\0` but you also must make sure that you own that memory. You must add `+1` in your calls to `malloc`

Comment: OT: there is a lot od code duplication, you should refactor your code and but the file reading stuff into a function.

Comment: BTW: when you mention ".tar file" do you mean this: https://docs.fileformat.com/compression/tar/

Comment: @Jabberwocky Yes! However the document that I used for reference was this, https://www.fileformat.info/format/tar/corion.htm
I also wanted to make sure I can write to the tar file before refactoring it to make it more iterative

Comment: Always check the return values of file read/write functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error resids in the way you calculate the total length. Indeed, you do not want to use `sizeof(file1_data)` as the length of the file. Instead you want to use the value returned when reading in `result`.

Create two variables `file1_length` and `file2_length`. Then populate them with the size of their respective file:

```
...
size_t f1_len, f2_len;
...
f = fopen(file1, "rb");
if (f == NULL) {
    printf("File error!");
    return 1;
}
fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END);
f1_size = ftell(f);
fseek(f, 0, SEEK_SET);
file1_data = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * f1_len);
...

int total = sizeof(struct header) + sizeof(struct header) + f1_len + f2_len;
...
fwrite(h1, sizeof(struct header), 1, f);
fwrite(file1_data, f1_len, 1, f);
fwrite(h2, sizeof(struct header), 1, f);
fwrite(file2_data, f2_len, 1, f);
...
```

Finally, use these variable as the length of the files' content.

NOTE: The value obtained by `sizeof(file1_data)` indicate the size of the type. Here, since `file1_data` is of type `char *` you get `4`.

Comment: Nowadays it is more lilkely to get `8` for a pointer on a PC like systems.

Comment: I see, however I only wanted to see what's the total amount of bytes that will be allocated out of my own curiosity. I'm not exactly sure how I can incorporate the variable total when using the fwrite functions?

Comment: @Gerhardh indeed ! I'm too much used to work with embedded 32bits devices ..

Comment: @tthh how is "out of curiosity" in the game here? You use `sizeof(file1_data)` as the bytecount for `fwrite`. You must fix it there.

Comment: `fseek()`/`ftell()` on a binary stream is [is not portable](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.9.2p3):  "A binary stream need not meaningfully support `fseek` calls with a whence value of `SEEK_END`."  In fact, [it's undefined behavior](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#note268): "Setting the file position indicator to end-of-file, as with `fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END)`, has undefined behavior for a binary stream..." Nevermind the problem with `ftell()` returning a mere `long`, which can be only 32 bits...

Comment: @Gerhardh I now see what both of you were referring to, have fixed it as such. Thank you!